# How can I add a custom block to the products page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I'm looking to add custom product attributes to the product page. Basically adding a block under the title to list product attributes.

I looked at echoing out the attributes in

```
Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

file but that seemed messy. So I was hoping there'd be a way to add a custom block to the xml and then rendering my own `.phtml` file? That way I'm keeping the core code seperate from my own (obviously I'm adding all this into my own theme files and not touching the vendor files.)

Would this be possible and/or the best way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `app\code\Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`
add like below code. You can use your required `referenceContainer`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="alert.urls">
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Module" name="textblock" as="textblock" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/textblock.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```